# Inserting shapedata to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, ogr2ogr

I am trying to insert .shp (shape file) to MySQL using ogr2ogr but I am getting following error:

> ERROR 1: MySQL error message:Too big scale 31 specified for column
>   'hght_lmt_m'. Maximum is 30. Description: ALTER TABLE
>   `shapefiledatabase` ADD COLUMN `hght_lmt_m` DOUBLE(33,31)

How to overcome this Limit ?

Answer (score 3):

MySQL validates, and then ignores, the numbers in parentheses after `DOUBLE` in column definitions.  It always uses [IEEE 64-bit double precision floating point for `DOUBLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/floating-point-types.html). If that isn't enough precision for you, you're probably an astronomer.

So take away the `(33,31)` from your definition and you should be fine.

OGR's MySQL driver offers a flag that tries to preserve precision (see [Layer Creation Options](http://www.gdal.org/drv_mysql.html)). Turn that flag off by setting `-lco PRECISION=false` on your ogr2ogr command.

Comment: Two doubts. As I haven't worked with shape file and ogr2ogr. How to remove definition as opening shapefile in notepad giving weird notation. And how to turn off the flag.

Comment: FAILURE: Unknown option name '-precision'